# Unable to parse meta-oe/conf/layer.conf

Tags: intel, yocto, bitbake, intel-galileo

When I want to build a yocto image for intel Galileo, 
I followed these instructions mentioned in the website

https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/03/04/creating-a-yocto-image-for-the-intel-galileo-board-using-split-layers

When I tried to execute the command

```
$ bitbake iot-devkit-prof-dev-image
```

I am getting

```
=============================================================================
 ERROR: Unable to parse /home/iotdk/meta-oe/meta-oe/conf/layer.conf: file /home/iotdk/meta-oe/meta-oe/conf/layer.conf not found
intel1@intel1-All-Series:~/iotdk/meta/recipes-core/os-release/build$ bitbake iot-devkit-prof-dev-image
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/intel1/iotdk/bitbake/lib/bb/cookerdata.py", line 174, in wrapped
    return func(fn, *args)
  File "/home/intel1/iotdk/bitbake/lib/bb/cookerdata.py", line 184, in parse_config_file
    return bb.parse.handle(fn, data, include)
  File "/home/intel1/iotdk/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/__init__.py", line 107, in handle
    return h['handle'](fn, data, include)
  File "/home/intel1/iotdk/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/parse_py/ConfHandler.py", line 120, in handle
    abs_fn = resolve_file(fn, data)
  File "/home/intel1/iotdk/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/__init__.py", line 130, in resolve_file
    raise IOError("file %s not found" % fn)
IOError: file /home/iotdk/meta-oe/meta-oe/conf/layer.conf not found

ERROR: Unable to parse /home/iotdk/meta-oe/meta-oe/conf/layer.conf: file /home/iotdk/meta-oe/meta-oe/conf/layer.conf not found
================================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your path for meta-oe in your `conf/bblayers.conf`. The layer path for meta-oe should be something like

```
/home/intel1/iotdk/meta-oe/meta-oe \
```

I think you are missing `intel1` after `/home/` for that line.

Answer (score 0):

when you add path to your bblayers.conf you should give some space at the end of the path before the backslash ()
sample path: \home\Downloads\poky\meta-intel \